# Input Manager name of Numpad Enter

Tags: input, numpad

I want to assign **Numpad enter** in the unity Inputmanager... but i can't

*[enter], numpad enter, keypad enter, [return], etc.*

nothing works.

Any ideas what it could be i didn't find any answer online

Comment: What is the error are you getting? Please show us what you have done so far? Code you have used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `enter` for **Numpad Enter** and `return` for **Enter**

[image]

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html

Comment: Omg it‘s so simple and not obvious at the Same time. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad To Help You!
If it helped you, consider `Accepting` the answer.